# Add two in Function to a button Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, flatbutton

how can I add two function to a single button?
I have a button that sends a request to a server and I would like to add a Dialog after sending the request... I tried this:

```
onPressed: () {
                _makePostRequest();
                showAlertDialog(context);
              },
```

But still not working...

The post code:

```
     _makePostRequest() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1/API');
    final headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
    final json = '{"id": "1", "status": "1"}';
    final response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    final statusCode = response.statusCode;
    final body = response.body;
  }
```

The Show Dialog code:

```
    void showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () {},
  );

  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("PMZ Label Print"),
    content: Text("Label is printing..."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to below code

Your Button

```
onPressed:(){
 _makePostRequest();
}
```

Your API Call

```
_makePostRequest() async {
final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1/API');
final headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
final json = '{"id": "1", "status": "1"}';
final response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
final statusCode = response.statusCode;
final body = response.body;
//your alert function call
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
 showAlertDialog(context);

} else {
  print(
    "Error",
   );
 }
}
```

I have try above code and my code is working

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Unhandled Exception: No MaterialLocalizations found.

Comment: you can go through my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210  see API call function and try to call API in this format and add your showAlert function inside `response.statusCode == 200` block and your API call function on button pressed

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add `async` on `onPressed`.

```
onPressed: ()async {
               await _makePostRequest();
                showAlertDialog(context);
              },
```

Answer (score 1):

_makePostRequest is of type Future so you can use 2 ways :

**`First one:`**

```
onPress:(){
_makePostRequest().then((v){
 showAlertDialog(context);

});
}
```

**`Second one:`**

```
onPress:()await {
 await YourFunction();
showAlertDialog(context);
    }
```