# No data from sever API's is not showing on Listview using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-listview

I'm fetching data from server APIs, The data is being successfully fetched from the server but the issue is that when the data is provided to Listview it cant be shown. How can I show the data on Listview in a flutter/dart?

Following is the code for fetching data from server API's

```
  List<String> jobTitles = [];
  List officeNames = [ ];
  List officeLocations = [ ];
  List jobTypes = [ ];

  Future getJobsData() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.https('hospitality92.com', 'api/jobsbycategory/All'));
    Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> jobData = map["jobs"];

    if (jobTitles.length != 0) {
      officeNames.clear();
      jobTitles.clear();
      officeLocations.clear();
      jobTypes.clear();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < jobData.length; i++) {
      jobTitles.add(jobData[i]["title"]);
      officeNames.add(jobData[i]["company_name"]);
      officeLocations.add(jobData[i]["company_name"]);
      jobTypes.add(jobData[i]["type"]);
    }

    /* print(jobTitles);
    print(officeNames);
    print(officeLocations);
    print(jobTypes);*/
  }
```

Here is the design code that I wanted to show:

```
  Widget listCard(jobTitle, officeName, location, jobType, onPress) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onPress,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Color(0xC000000), Color(0xC000000)])),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/ic_login.png",
                        height: 28,
                        width: 28,
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      jobTitle,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.lightBlue,
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.home_outlined,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              size: 16,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              officeName,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.location_pin,
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              size: 16,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 2,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              location,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),

                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 4, 0, 0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                                Colors.lightBlueAccent
                              ])),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  jobType,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )

                        //ElevatedButton(onPressed: () { }, child: Text("Full Time", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the listview code

```
ListView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: jobTitle.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return listCard(jobTitles[index], officeNames[index],
                          officeLocations[index], jobTypes[index], () {});
                    }),
```

If I provide the static data to list it will show on listview, but dynamic data is not being shown.

Comment: If you want get data please follow my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I tried this way but still didn't get response. 
My JSON formate is like this one:
`{
"jobs": [
{
"title": "Laravel SENIOR DEVELOPER",
"company_name": "Envato",
"type": "Full Time",
},
],
"jobcount": 2,
"category": "All"
}`

Comment: Can you tell me you print your json data inside **FutureBuilder** using **snapshot**

Comment: see my below answer and your problem has been  solved

Comment: In following url u can add img url and get img url and used NetworkImage widget and pass the url in that NetworkImage widget or add image url in this API I get the answer proper way if u don't understand

Comment: https://hospitality92.com/api/jobsbycategory/All.   In this API not image url present please add img url in this API I will try to solve your problem don't worry

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil sir how can we search for jobs on basis of job category from this populated list of jobs.

Comment: You want search jobs in list correct?

Comment: can you see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68624790/13997210) its correct your need, in this answer I search the name

Comment: If any query in above link answer let me know

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil  error occurs **[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.**

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil no data found in list

Comment: you try this answer?

Comment: Try this example its working finely for me

Comment: sir, I think my JSON response is not suitable for that example, I think their is problem in JSON response

Comment: Just try on your Side if it is not solved on your side, I will try to solve your problem at tonight

Comment: Your problem has been solved just check my answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671/13997210)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try To below Code Your problem has been solved:

**Create API Call Function**

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> getJobsData() async {
    String url = 'https://hospitality92.com/api/jobsbycategory/All';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    return json.decode(response.body)['jobs'];
  }
```

**Write/Create your Widget :**

```
Center( 
    child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: getJobsData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var title = snapshot.data[index]['title'];
                  var company = snapshot.data[index]['company_name'];
                  var skills = snapshot.data[index]['skills'];
                  var description = snapshot.data[index]['description'];
                  var positions = snapshot.data[index]['positions'];
                  return Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.green.shade300,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Text(skills),
                      title: Text(title),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        company + '\n' + description,
                      ),
                      trailing: Text(positions),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    ),
```

**Your Screen Look Like**

[image]