# Error in searching data using listview in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I've tried this code for searching jobs in listview but the data is not shown in listview. I think JSON is not parsing properly for Jobs data.

Here is the code of the model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class JobItem {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  JobItem(
      { 
      required this.title,
        required this.description,
        });

  factory JobItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return JobItem(
      title: json['title'] as String,
      description: json['description'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Here I've written code for the main file to search data from the listview.

````
 List<JobItem> users = [];
  List<JobItem> filteredUsers = [];
  static String url = 'https://hospitality92.com/api/jobsbycategory/All';

  static Future<List<JobItem>> getJobsData() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<JobItem> list = parseAgents(response.body);

        return list;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }
  static List<JobItem> parseAgents(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<JobItem>((json) => JobItem.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getJobsData().then((usersFromServer) {
      setState(() {
        users = usersFromServer;
        filteredUsers = users;
      });
    });
  }```
````

Comment: have you checked the value from `getJobData()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code your problem has been solved :

```
//declare packages
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Jobs extends StatefulWidget {
  Jobs() : super();

  @override
  JobsState createState() => JobsState();
}

class Debouncer {
  final int milliseconds;
  VoidCallback action;
  Timer _timer;

  Debouncer({this.milliseconds});

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (null != _timer) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds), action);
  }
}

class JobsState extends State<Jobs> {
  final _debouncer = Debouncer(milliseconds: 500);

  List<Subject> subjects = [];
  List<Subject> filteredSubjects = [];
  //API call for All Subject List

  static String url = 'https://hospitality92.com/api/jobsbycategory/All';

  static Future<List<Subject>> getAllSubjectsList() async {
    try {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      List<Subject> list = parseAgents(response.body);

      return list;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Error');
    }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static List<Subject> parseAgents(String responseBody) {
    final parsed =
        json.decode(responseBody)['jobs'].cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Subject>((json) => Subject.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllSubjectsList().then((subjectFromServer) {
      setState(() {
        subjects = subjectFromServer;
        filteredSubjects = subjects;
      });
    });
  }

  //Main Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'All Subjects',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Search Bar to List of typed Subject
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                suffixIcon: InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Search ',
              ),
              onChanged: (string) {
                _debouncer.run(() {
                  setState(() {
                    filteredSubjects = subjects
                        .where((u) => (u.title
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .contains(string.toLowerCase())))
                        .toList();
                  });
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          //Lists of Subjects
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
              itemCount: filteredSubjects.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    side: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Text(
                            filteredSubjects[index].skills,
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            filteredSubjects[index].title,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(filteredSubjects[index].position.toString()),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Declare Subject class for json data or parameters of json string/data
//Class For Subject
  class Subject {
  String title;
  int id;
  String skills;
  String position;
  Subject({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.skills,
    this.position,
  });

  factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Subject(
        title: json['title'] as String,
        id: json['id'],
        skills: json['skills'],
        position: json['positions']);
  }
}
```

Your screen before search: [image]

Your Screen after search : [image]

Comment: Will this cause the API endpoint to be hit again when a search term is inputted? Or does this just obtain all the data and then filter it as the user enters a search term?

Comment: @dingo can't understand can you explain in brief what do you want

Answer (score 0):

U have a little mistake in parsing. I added `response.body['jobs']`.

```
static Future<List<JobItem>> getJobsData() async {
try {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List<JobItem> list = parseAgents(Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(response.body))['jobs']);

    return list;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception(e.toString());
} }
```

Comment: sir following error occurs. ** A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'. List<JobItem> list = parseAgents(response.body['jobs']);  **

Comment: I changed the function a bit. Try it now!