# how to implement search listview in flutter

Tags: flutter

bloc.dart

```
part 'news_article_loader_event.dart';
part 'news_article_loader_state.dart';
part 'news_article_loader_bloc.freezed.dart';

@injectable
class NewsArticleLoaderBloc
    extends Bloc<NewsArticleLoaderEvent, NewsArticleLoaderState> {
  NewsArticleLoaderBloc(this.iBlogPost)
      : super(NewsArticleLoaderState.initial());

  final INewsArticle iBlogPost;

  @override
  Stream<NewsArticleLoaderState> mapEventToState(
      NewsArticleLoaderEvent event) async* {
    yield NewsArticleLoaderState.loadInProgress();
    final failureOrSuccess = await iBlogPost.getDataNews();
    yield failureOrSuccess.fold((l) => NewsArticleLoaderState.loadFailure(l),
        (r) => NewsArticleLoaderState.loadSuccess(r));
  }
}
```

repository.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:mone/app_constant.dart';
import 'package:mone/model/news/blog_post.dart';
import 'package:mone/repositories/i_news_repository.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

@Injectable(as: INewsArticle)
class BLogPostRepository implements INewsArticle {
  final Dio dio;
  // int page = 1;
  final SharedPreferences prefs;

  BLogPostRepository(this.dio, this.prefs);

  @override
  Future<Either<String, List<NewsBlogModel>>> getDataNews() async {
    try {
      final token = prefs.get(kAccesTokenKey);
      String url = '/api/v1/cms?size=30';
      var response = await dio.get(url,
          options: Options(
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'aplication/json',
              'Authorization': 'bearer $token',
            },
          ));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final listNews = (response.data['items'] as List)
            .map((e) => NewsBlogModel.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList();
        return right(listNews);
      }
      return left('error: ${response.statusCode}');
    } catch (e) {
      return left('error get data $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<String, List<NewsBlogModel>>> getDataNewsbyId() async {
    // TODO: implement getDataNewsbyId
    try {
      final token = prefs.get(kAccesTokenKey);
      String urlbyid = '/api/v1/cms/id';
      var response = await dio.get(urlbyid,
          options: Options(headers: {
            'Accept': 'aplication/json',
            'Authorization': 'bearer $token',
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final dataNewsbyId = (response.data['items'] as List)
            .map((e) => NewsBlogModel.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList();
        return right(dataNewsbyId);
      }
      return left("error:${response.statusCode}");
    } catch (e) {
      return left("error get data $e");
    }
  }
}
```

**I have the code below where I have provided the BLoC code for the code and also for the repository code. but I'm still confused about how to connect it to the UI that I made. explanation please.
below also my code has succeeded to call all data list from API. but when I want to try to find the data list in the get, but can't.
UI.dart**

```
part of '../screens.dart';

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewsScreenState createState() => _NewsScreenState();
}

class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {
  Widget customTitleBar = const Text('Berita');
  Icon customIcon = new Icon(Icons.search, color: primaryColor);

  TextEditingController filterController = TextEditingController();

 


  // String filter = '';

  // void initState(){
    
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // bloc provider berguna untuk menambahkan data dari bloc ke ui,

    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          getIt<NewsArticleLoaderBloc>()..add(NewsArticleLoaderEvent.started()),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: customTitleBar,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (this.customIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                    this.customIcon =
                        new Icon(Icons.close, color: primaryColor, size: 30);
                    this.customTitleBar = new TextField(
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search,
                              color: primaryColor, size: 30),
                          hintText: "Search...",
                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      cursorColor: primaryColor,
                      onChanged: (value) async {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {

                          setState(() {});
                          return;
                        }
                       
                      },
                      controller:filterController,
                    );
                  } else {
                    this.customIcon =
                        new Icon(Icons.search, color: primaryColor, size: 30);
                    this.customTitleBar = new Text("Berita");
                  }
                });
              },
              icon: customIcon,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<NewsArticleLoaderBloc, NewsArticleLoaderState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return state.map(
              initial: (_) => Container(),
              loadInProgress: (_) => Center(
                child: SpinKitCircle(
                  color: primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              loadFailure: (state) => Center(
                child: Text(state.failure),
              ),
              loadSuccess: (state) {
                if (state.datenews.isEmpty) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text("data tidak di temukan"),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.separated(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    itemCount: state.datenews.length,
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        height: 4,
                      );
                    },
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final newsBlog = state.datenews[index];
                      return ContentNews(
                        newsBlog: newsBlog,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).