# how to search from data in api [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Im currently trying to list a bunch of quotes from an api. that list would have a search delegate to filter the user's choices; however, the search delegate isnt showing any results. how should I go about this problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Search extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  List quotes = [];
  String author = "";
  String result = "";

  Search({
    required this.author,
  });

  Future<List<dynamic>> getPost() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.https('type.fit', 'api/quotes'));
    return postFromJson(response.body);
  }

  List<dynamic> postFromJson(String str) {
    List<dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(str);
    quotes = jsonData.toList();
    print("shet");
    return jsonData;
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, result);
        print("tangina");
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestions = quotes.where((quotes) {
      return quotes.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
    });

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestions.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            suggestions.elementAt(index),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            result = suggestions.elementAt(index);
            close(context, result);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestions = quotes.where((quotes) {
      return quotes.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
    });

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestions.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            suggestions.elementAt(index),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            query = suggestions.elementAt(index);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

the code above is the search delegate dart file

```
class QuoteModel {
  String? text;
  String? author;

  QuoteModel({required this.text, required this.author});

  QuoteModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    text = json['text'];
    author = json['author'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['text'] = this.text;
    data['author'] = this.author;
    return data;
  }
}
```

above is the model.dart for the quotes

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterquote/model/search.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}

class Quote {
  final String author;
  final String text;

  Quote({required this.author, required this.text});
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  Future<List<dynamic>> getPost() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.https('type.fit', 'api/quotes'));
    return postFromJson(response.body);
  }

  List<dynamic> postFromJson(String str) {
    List<dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(str);
    List quotes = jsonData.toList();
    print(quotes[0]);
    return jsonData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff171717),
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 80,
          title: Text(''),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () async {
                final result = await showSearch<String>(
                  context: context,
                  delegate: Search(author: ""),
                );

                print(result);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Color(0xff171717),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getPost(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot);
                  return ErrorWidget(snapshot);
                }
                return ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    var model = snapshot.data![index];
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.format_quote),
                      title: Text(
                        model["text"].toString(),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        model["author"].toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

and this is where the list should appear

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Comment: unfortunately, it didnt work, thanks though

Comment: the list is still not showing up whenever i try to search anything

Comment: Ok can you share your API url I will test it on my machine

Comment: "https://type.fit/api/quotes" is the API url I used

Comment: try my below answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below answer hope its helpful to you.

```
//declare packages
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Jobs extends StatefulWidget {
  Jobs() : super();

  @override
  JobsState createState() => JobsState();
}

class Debouncer {
  int? milliseconds;
  VoidCallback? action;
  Timer? timer;

  run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (null != timer) {
      timer!.cancel();
    }
    timer = Timer(
      Duration(milliseconds: Duration.millisecondsPerSecond),
      action,
    );
  }
}

class JobsState extends State<Jobs> {
  final _debouncer = Debouncer();

  List<Subject> ulist = [];
  List<Subject> userLists = [];
  //API call for All Subject List

  String url = 'https://type.fit/api/quotes';

  Future<List<Subject>> getAllulistList() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // print(response.body);
        List<Subject> list = parseAgents(response.body);
        return list;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static List<Subject> parseAgents(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Subject>((json) => Subject.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllulistList().then((subjectFromServer) {
      setState(() {
        ulist = subjectFromServer;
        userLists = ulist;
      });
    });
  }

  //Main Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'All Users',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Search Bar to List of typed Subject
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: TextField(
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                suffixIcon: InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                hintText: 'Search ',
              ),
              onChanged: (string) {
                _debouncer.run(() {
                  setState(() {
                    userLists = ulist
                        .where(
                          (u) => (u.text.toLowerCase().contains(
                                string.toLowerCase(),
                              )),
                        )
                        .toList();
                  });
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              itemCount: userLists.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    side: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            userLists[index].text,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            userLists[index].author ?? "null",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Declare Subject class for json data or parameters of json string/data
//Class For Subject
class Subject {
  var text;
  var author;
  Subject({
    required this.text,
    required this.author,
  });

  factory Subject.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return Subject(
      text: json['text'],
      author: json['author'],
    );
  }
}
```

Your result screen before search -> [image]

Your result screen after search -> [image]

Comment: thank you so much this worked like a charm, Im currently analyzing what went wrong on my end. again Thank youuu

Comment: Most welcome @RobinRivera Enjoy your ride with flutter