# How to make search FLUTTER JSON

Tags: flutter

I'm a new Flutter user, here I'm having a problem, I'm confused about how to make a search that reads from JSON, here I've created a search menu but I don't understand how to connect to the database. Can you help me to modify my source code so I can do a search. Hopefully good friends can help me make a search function. Thank you friend

**datanasabah.dart**

```
   GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
        class DataNasabah extends StatefulWidget {
          DataNasabah({Key key}) : super(key: key);
          final String title = "Data Nasabah";
        
          @override
          _DataNasabahState createState() => _DataNasabahState();
        }
        
        class _DataNasabahState extends State<DataNasabah> {
          ApiService apiService;
          ListNasabah _listNasabah;
          bool _isLoading = true;
          List<Nasabah> data;
          final _textHeadStyle =
              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
        
          void fetchData() async {
            final res = await apiService.getNasabah();
            data = res;
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
            });
          }
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            apiService = ApiService();
            _listNasabah = new ListNasabah(apiService: apiService);
            fetchData();
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldState,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(
                  'Data Nasabah',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    elevation: 5,
                    child:  Text("CARI", style: _textHeadStyle),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var value = await showTopModalSheet<String>(
                          context: context, child: DumyModal());
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: _listNasabah.createViewList(),
            );
          }
        }
        
        class DumyModal extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .2,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "NIK Nasabah", //babel text
                        hintText: "Masukkan NIK Nasabah", //hint text
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.people), //prefix iocn
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, ), //hint text style
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black), //label style
                      )
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: const Text("Cari", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                    onPressed: () {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

**nasabah_service.dart**

```
class ApiService {
  final String baseUrl = '192.168.100.207:8080';

  Client client = Client();

  Future<List<Nasabah>> getNasabah() async {
    final response = await client.get('http://$baseUrl/api/mstdebitur');
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final nasabah = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((e) => Nasabah.fromMap(e))
          .toList();
      return nasabah;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> createNasabah(Nasabah data) async {
    String url = new Uri.http("$baseUrl", "/api/mstdebitur/").toString();
    final response = await client.post(url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: nasabahToJson(data));
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> updateNasabah(Nasabah data) async {
    String url =
    new Uri.http("$baseUrl", "/api/mstdebitur/${data.id}").toString();
    final response = await client.put(url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: nasabahToJson(data));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> deleteNasabah(int id) async {
    String url = new Uri.http("$baseUrl", "/api/mstdebitur/$id").toString();
    final response = await client.delete(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want search data from `JSON` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972824/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil can you help me to modify my source code ? because I'm a new user so confused :')

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Please help me , Because I'm confused about flutter because I'm still a beginner

Comment: Azmi Badhi'uz Zaman are you try my solutions?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes, but I was confused and an error occurred, so please can you help modify my source code :(

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: lib/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart:78:27: Error: The getter '_debouncer' isn't defined for the class '_DataNasabahState'.

Comment: lib/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart:80:43: Error: The getter 'ulist' isn't defined for the class '_DataNasabahState'.
 - '_DataNasabahState' is from 'package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart' ('lib/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ulist'.
                              userLists = ulist
                                          ^^^^^

Comment: lib/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart:80:31: Error: The setter 'userLists' isn't defined for the class '_DataNasabahState'.
 - '_DataNasabahState' is from 'package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart' ('lib/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'userLists'.
                              userLists = ulist
                              ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: lib/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart:77:34: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.
                      onPressed: (string) {
                                 ^

Comment: can you share your API url?

Comment: http://192.168.100.207:8080/api/mstdebitur  -> http://replace with your IP:8080/api/mstdebitur"

Comment: this not display any response

Comment: try 192.168.100.207:8080/api/mstdebitur

Comment: because I use a local network @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil bro can you help me ? this is my  API you can now access it fleetime.herokuapp.com/api/tbluser

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Please help me bro :(

Comment: Please host your API url and provide me I will work on that, If you refer my answer so try to implement same

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil, how can we use your snippet for Wordpress REST API calls? The JSON data looks like this: "title": {
      "rendered": "The Girls"
    },