# Add json response in list Flutter

Tags: flutter

I successfully fetched data from api and its in json form, now i want to store all "data" from response list but its fired me error like this "String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'". I am new in flutter so please help me how to store this response in my List.

API response:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": "found",
  "data": [
    {
      "ref_id": "37",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "Sakina hall",
      "city_name": "Mahuva",
      "description": "no detail",
      "end_date": "14-01-2023",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG1423956606.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "Molana sahab",
      "postDateTime": "05-01-2023 11:49 AM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "no notes",
      "start_date": "07-01-2023",
      "time": "10:00 AM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
      "status": "Ongoing"
    },
    {
      "ref_id": "39",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "aaa",
      "city_name": "sss",
      "description": "ssss",
      "end_date": "05-01-2023",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG869535151.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "ssss",
      "postDateTime": "05-01-2023 12:07 PM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "ss",
      "start_date": "05-01-2023",
      "time": "12:07 PM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
      "status": "Past"
    },
    {
      "ref_id": "38",
      "postId": "106764933065187174744",
      "azakhana_name": "Najaf Hall",
      "city_name": "Mahuva",
      "description": "no detail",
      "end_date": "10-01-2023",
      "image_path": "Posts_Images\/POST-IMG1677242263.jpg",
      "name_of_schollar": "Molana ghareem abbas",
      "postDateTime": "05-01-2023 11:51 AM",
      "program_list": "Majlis",
      "special_notes": "no notes",
      "start_date": "04-01-2023",
      "time": "11:00 AM",
      "user_name": "Taki Rajani",
      "status": "Past"
    }
  ],
  "totalPosts": "5",
  "totalPages": 2,
  "perPageLimit": 3,
  "currentPage": 1,
  "hasNextPage": 1
}
```

Get api response method:

```
Future<List<UserPostModel>> getUserPost() async {

    var url =
        "APIgetUserPost.php?page=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    Map<String,dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<dynamic> data1 = data["data"];

    //This print give me perfect answer
    print(data1[0]["azakhana_name"]);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      for (var i in data1){
        myList.add(UserPostModel.fromJson(i));
      }

      print(myList);

      return myList;

    } else {
      print("failed");
      return myList;
    }
  }
```

My model class which created by plugin (jsonToDart) I used this plug in:

Model calss:

```
class UserPostModel {
  UserPostModel({
      bool? status, 
      String? result, 
      List<Data>? data, 
      String? totalPosts, 
      num? totalPages, 
      num? perPageLimit, 
      num? currentPage, 
      num? hasNextPage,}){
    _status = status;
    _result = result;
    _data = data;
    _totalPosts = totalPosts;
    _totalPages = totalPages;
    _perPageLimit = perPageLimit;
    _currentPage = currentPage;
    _hasNextPage = hasNextPage;
}

  UserPostModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _status = json['status'];
    _result = json['result'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      _data = [];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        _data?.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    _totalPosts = json['totalPosts'];
    _totalPages = json['totalPages'];
    _perPageLimit = json['perPageLimit'];
    _currentPage = json['currentPage'];
    _hasNextPage = json['hasNextPage'];
  }
  bool? _status;
  String? _result;
  List<Data>? _data;
  String? _totalPosts;
  num? _totalPages;
  num? _perPageLimit;
  num? _currentPage;
  num? _hasNextPage;
UserPostModel copyWith({  bool? status,
  String? result,
  List<Data>? data,
  String? totalPosts,
  num? totalPages,
  num? perPageLimit,
  num? currentPage,
  num? hasNextPage,
}) => UserPostModel(  status: status ?? _status,
  result: result ?? _result,
  data: data ?? _data,
  totalPosts: totalPosts ?? _totalPosts,
  totalPages: totalPages ?? _totalPages,
  perPageLimit: perPageLimit ?? _perPageLimit,
  currentPage: currentPage ?? _currentPage,
  hasNextPage: hasNextPage ?? _hasNextPage,
);
  bool? get status => _status;
  String? get result => _result;
  List<Data>? get data => _data;
  String? get totalPosts => _totalPosts;
  num? get totalPages => _totalPages;
  num? get perPageLimit => _perPageLimit;
  num? get currentPage => _currentPage;
  num? get hasNextPage => _hasNextPage;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['status'] = _status;
    map['result'] = _result;
    if (_data != null) {
      map['data'] = _data?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['totalPosts'] = _totalPosts;
    map['totalPages'] = _totalPages;
    map['perPageLimit'] = _perPageLimit;
    map['currentPage'] = _currentPage;
    map['hasNextPage'] = _hasNextPage;
    return map;
  }

}

/// ref_id : "37"
/// postId : "106764933065187174744"
/// azakhana_name : "Sakina hall"
/// city_name : "Mahuva"
/// description : "no detail"
/// end_date : "14-01-2023"
/// image_path : "Posts_Images/POST-IMG1423956606.jpg"
/// name_of_schollar : "Molana sahab"
/// postDateTime : "05-01-2023 11:49 AM"
/// program_list : "Majlis"
/// special_notes : "no notes"
/// start_date : "07-01-2023"
/// time : "10:00 AM"
/// user_name : "Taki Rajani"
/// status : "Ongoing"

class Data {
  Data({
      String? refId, 
      String? postId, 
      String? azakhanaName, 
      String? cityName, 
      String? description, 
      String? endDate, 
      String? imagePath, 
      String? nameOfSchollar, 
      String? postDateTime, 
      String? programList, 
      String? specialNotes, 
      String? startDate, 
      String? time, 
      String? userName, 
      String? status,}){
    _refId = refId;
    _postId = postId;
    _azakhanaName = azakhanaName;
    _cityName = cityName;
    _description = description;
    _endDate = endDate;
    _imagePath = imagePath;
    _nameOfSchollar = nameOfSchollar;
    _postDateTime = postDateTime;
    _programList = programList;
    _specialNotes = specialNotes;
    _startDate = startDate;
    _time = time;
    _userName = userName;
    _status = status;
}

  Data.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _refId = json['ref_id'];
    _postId = json['postId'];
    _azakhanaName = json['azakhana_name'];
    _cityName = json['city_name'];
    _description = json['description'];
    _endDate = json['end_date'];
    _imagePath = json['image_path'];
    _nameOfSchollar = json['name_of_schollar'];
    _postDateTime = json['postDateTime'];
    _programList = json['program_list'];
    _specialNotes = json['special_notes'];
    _startDate = json['start_date'];
    _time = json['time'];
    _userName = json['user_name'];
    _status = json['status'];
  }
  String? _refId;
  String? _postId;
  String? _azakhanaName;
  String? _cityName;
  String? _description;
  String? _endDate;
  String? _imagePath;
  String? _nameOfSchollar;
  String? _postDateTime;
  String? _programList;
  String? _specialNotes;
  String? _startDate;
  String? _time;
  String? _userName;
  String? _status;
Data copyWith({  String? refId,
  String? postId,
  String? azakhanaName,
  String? cityName,
  String? description,
  String? endDate,
  String? imagePath,
  String? nameOfSchollar,
  String? postDateTime,
  String? programList,
  String? specialNotes,
  String? startDate,
  String? time,
  String? userName,
  String? status,
}) => Data(  refId: refId ?? _refId,
  postId: postId ?? _postId,
  azakhanaName: azakhanaName ?? _azakhanaName,
  cityName: cityName ?? _cityName,
  description: description ?? _description,
  endDate: endDate ?? _endDate,
  imagePath: imagePath ?? _imagePath,
  nameOfSchollar: nameOfSchollar ?? _nameOfSchollar,
  postDateTime: postDateTime ?? _postDateTime,
  programList: programList ?? _programList,
  specialNotes: specialNotes ?? _specialNotes,
  startDate: startDate ?? _startDate,
  time: time ?? _time,
  userName: userName ?? _userName,
  status: status ?? _status,
);
  String? get refId => _refId;
  String? get postId => _postId;
  String? get azakhanaName => _azakhanaName;
  String? get cityName => _cityName;
  String? get description => _description;
  String? get endDate => _endDate;
  String? get imagePath => _imagePath;
  String? get nameOfSchollar => _nameOfSchollar;
  String? get postDateTime => _postDateTime;
  String? get programList => _programList;
  String? get specialNotes => _specialNotes;
  String? get startDate => _startDate;
  String? get time => _time;
  String? get userName => _userName;
  String? get status => _status;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['ref_id'] = _refId;
    map['postId'] = _postId;
    map['azakhana_name'] = _azakhanaName;
    map['city_name'] = _cityName;
    map['description'] = _description;
    map['end_date'] = _endDate;
    map['image_path'] = _imagePath;
    map['name_of_schollar'] = _nameOfSchollar;
    map['postDateTime'] = _postDateTime;
    map['program_list'] = _programList;
    map['special_notes'] = _specialNotes;
    map['start_date'] = _startDate;
    map['time'] = _time;
    map['user_name'] = _userName;
    map['status'] = _status;
    return map;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you want to apply search filter on API list then try to refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972824/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) hope its help to you.

Comment: sir i want response in my list/array. @RavindraS.Patil

Answer (score 1):

json by default returns `String`, You need to explicity convert it into `bool` as below

```
UserPostModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _status = json['status'] == "true";  Add this condition this will convert String to bool
    _result = json['result'];
     ...
  }
```

Comment: its fired me this error [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Comment: But this is another error, Your `"String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'"`. error is resolved !!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671441/flutter-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1 Refer this for your above mentioned error

Comment: after add 'bool' its fired me error "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type cast" same error

Comment: print(myList);  output is print(myList); still not added response in array

Comment: your code logic would be wrong, you need to debug every line but I guess answer to the said question is solved ! `"String' is not a subtype of type 'bool'"` did this go ?

Comment: thanks sir, but in title also i said i want to add response in my list. sir please solve. all my codeing and logic are posted in my question if it need any changes please tell me i will change, i am stuck in this problem from couple of days. please look one more time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251208/discussion-between-krishna-acharya-and-taki-rajani).