# Flutter search item from ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to search item from ListView but I can't seem to find a way. What I want is when I type in the contact name from my contact list, then the specific contact appears on the page.

Here is my search code:

```
Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Color(0xff99999B),
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            contactList = contactList.where((element) => element.contains(value)).toList();
                          });
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search contact...',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff99999B),
                                fontSize: 12
                            ...
```

And my ListView code:

```
Container(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: contactList.length,
                          itemBuilder:(BuildContext context,index)=>
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                   Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                                      child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              ConstrainedBox(
                                                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                    maxWidth: 250
                                                ),
                                                child: Text(contactList[index].userName!,
                                                  ...
```

Is there any solutions?

Comment: what you want to achieve.in your method contact list reset each time you search . and you cant search properly because contact list size always reduce

Comment: yes that's what I want

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671) hope its help to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var contactList = ["asi", "adi", "java", "c++", "Kotlin", "Dart", "Flutter"];
var contactList2 = [];
```

consider create two list keep the original list and manage the secondlist for filtering .look below example

[image]

Your widget like

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Row(children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Color(0xff99999B),
                size: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          contactList2 = contactList
                              .where((element) => element
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                              .toList();
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Search contact...',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff99999B), fontSize: 12))))
            ]),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: contactList2.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        contactList2[index],
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Color(0xff99999B), fontSize: 25),
                      ),
                    )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**SAmpleCode**  [DArtpad live code check here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=31084d2f6ba19c025d1c330aa8665604)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:pucon/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Parent(),
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Parent> createState() => _ParentState();
}

var contactList = ["Asif", "adi", "java", "c++", "Kotlin", "Dart", "Flutter"];
var contactList2 = [];

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Row(children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Color(0xff99999B),
                size: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          contactList2 = contactList
                              .where((element) => element
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                              .toList();
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Search contact...',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff99999B), fontSize: 12))))
            ]),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: contactList2.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        contactList2[index],
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Color(0xff99999B), fontSize: 25),
                      ),
                    )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```