# initstate not executing before building widget

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to get json data from OMDb but my initstate function is not exicuting i figure it out by using print statement in side initsate funtion, but i dont know why it is not showing movies.statuscode

```
 void main() {
  print("runned");
  runApp(MovieApp());
}

class MovieApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MovieApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MovieAppState createState() => _MovieAppState();
}

class _MovieAppState extends State<MovieApp> {
  @override
  void initstate() {
    super.initState();
    print("pass");
    loaddata();
  }

  loaddata() async {
    String url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2&apikey=2c8219b0";
final movies = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    print(movies.statusCode);
  }
```

Comment: You never call the `loaddata()` function. Your `initstate()` does not run at start because it should be `initState()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. `initstate` is not equal to `initState`. Try this:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("pass");
    loaddata();
  }
```

Btw `loaddata` should also be by convention `loadData`.

Comment: An advice: for example in Visual Studio Code if you install Dart / Flutter extensions, you get warned if you make typos like that and you can spare some struggle.

Answer (score 0):

If you get data from API please go to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210)     and add your api URL like this http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2&apikey=2c8219b0

Create API call function

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> getJobsData() async {
String url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2&apikey=2c8219b0';
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
 });
 print(response.statusCode);
 print(response.body);
 return json.decode(response.body)['search'];
}
```

Comment: I changed that api url but still dosnt show any response but if i call loaddata() in widget it will show movies.statusCode = 200

Comment: @Loop check my API call function and try this

Comment: still nothing, i think so you have fixed API call fuction but there is still some problem in initstate function as it dosnt print "pass"

Comment: what was the problem and try to refer my answer link in above answer