# How to return Future<Response> in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a function on Flutter, which fetches data from an API. After the function is done, I need to return variable as `Future<Response>`

Here is the function:

```
final String apiUrl =  "http://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city=Kayseri&country=Turkey&method=13&month=07&year=2021";

Future<Response> fetchData() async {
 var result = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));
 return result;
}
```

However, I get this message from the compiler:

```
The name 'Response' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'Response'
```

Is there any other way to return that variable?

Thank you

Comment: If you get data from API please refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210 or here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210

Comment: whenever i stuck with variable type. i do `print(v.runtimeType);` so that i can sure of my return type. check @Huthaifa Muayyad answer.

Comment: You haven't  _import_ the `Response` to your code. Check `http.get` method return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Future<http.Response>
```

Use http because that's how you imported it.