# How to call nested json data using API in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
Info: [
       {
         c_type_id: "1",
         cleaning type: "A Cleaning"
        },
        {
          c_type_id: "2",
          cleaning type: "B Cleaning"
         },
         {
           c_type_id: "3",
           cleaning type: "C Cleaning"
         },
         {
           c_type_id: "4",
           cleaning type: "D Cleaning"
          },
          {
            c_type_id: "5",
            cleaning type: "E Cleaning"
           },
       ]
}
```

and here is the code:
The following code is created by [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)
Class 1:

```
class Album {
   List<Info> info;
   Album({this.info})
     Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      if (json['Info'] != null) {
       info =  List<Info>.empty();
       json['Info'].forEach((v) {
       info.add(new Info.fromJson(v));
      });
     }
    }

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
     final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
      if (this.info != null) {
      data['Info'] = this.info.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
      }
     return data;
     }
    }
```

class 2:

```
class Info {
  String cTypeId;
  String cleaningType;
  Info({this.cTypeId, this.cleaningType});
    Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    cTypeId = json['c_type_id'];
    cleaningType = json['cleaning type'];
    }
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
   final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
   data['c_type_id'] = this.cTypeId;
   data['cleaning type'] = this.cleaningType;
   return data;
 }
}
```

This is the error I get when I execute the code:
**error:** **The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.**

[image]

Hoping for help!

Comment: check this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: If you get data From API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210)

Comment: also the `json` data you provided is not a valid `JSON`.

Comment: @Ravindra S. Patil, I tried both but I didn't get output. 
Now, this error is showing "error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Album'"

Comment: can you tell me your json data is host online? because my second answer json data and your json data is look like same

Comment: yes, I have copy-pasted the JSON data here on above and I have followed 2nd answer.  @Ravindra S. Patil

Comment: Can you share your json url I try to solve your problem

Comment: @parveen check my answer your problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Try below code your problem has been solved ->

Declare your API Call funtion

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getInfoData() async {
    String url = 'https://fillmmaka.com/gigocleanapi/cleanintypes.php';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    return json.decode(response.body)['Info'];
  }
```

Declare your Widget

```
Center(
    child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      future: getInfoData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var id = snapshot.data[index]['c_type_id'];
                var type = snapshot.data[index]['cleaning type'];

                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.green.shade300,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(id),
                    title: Text(type),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Your Screen look like this -> [image]

Comment: hi sir ravindra. can i comment here a follow-up question related to this problem? thanks

Comment: @KimLo Yes sure, say your problem

Comment: what if i have a similar list, but this time it is nested. How do i make each textfield of the sublist unique? bcoz in my program now, whenever i input 55 on the textfield, it will change all the textfield on the sublist with the same index. thanks! see image link. https://imgur.com/IjOqWPJ

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the whole list there just use `snapshot.data.info[index].variableName` you want to access
and you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal? What do you want to show on the screen?
For example, do you want to show a list with all the cleaning types?

You are getting this error because the attribute `info` in your `Album` class is a List:

```
class Album {
   List<Info> info;
```

If you want to show the `cleaningType` of the first info on the list, you may do something like this:

```
return Text(snapshot.data.info[0].cleaningType);
```

Just keep in mind this will crash if the `info` list is empty.

Comment: and what if i want to show all the list data?