# Issue with JSON and Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

First off, let me apologise for any mistakes, as this is my first post.

Now, for the actual issue:

I've coded a PHP script that handles MySQL Queries, including one that fetches all data from a certain table.

I made it so the final result is a JSON object, containing all rows from said table.

I also coded a Flutter class (Dart) that handles the request for the JSON object via the URL, and I got it to successfully log said JSON to the console.

However, when I use that data to show on an actual List of Widgets, this is what appears on screen:

[Error Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTnAR.jpg)

Any ideas on how to fix this?
(For NDA reasons, I am not allowed to show the console logs.).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you get Data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you very much @RavindraS.Patil ! It works flawlessly after implementing your "fix" from the third answer you referred.

Comment: Most Welcome , and thanks to you refer my answer and your problem has been solved