# Flutter / Dart http request get method of my API ROUTE does not return response in body

Tags: flutter, response

This is my response from POSTMAN
[image]

I want to display thumbnail url image into Flutter Gridview Builder.

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $bearer_token'
  };
  var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stg/assets'));

  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
  }
  else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
}
```

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $bearer_token'
  };
  var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stg/assets'));
  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
  }
  else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
}

Comment: If you get Data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210)  or  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210)  or  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210)  hope its help to you

Answer (score 0):

i dont know it work for you but i did this which give me everything fine

```
       Future getSections(BuildContext context,String token,int id) async {
try {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse('${links.classesUrl}/$id${links.sectionListUrl}');
  Response response = await get(uri, headers: {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
  });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
```

}}

Comment: Ok. How to map this json string into DART OBJECT and how to generate thumbnail image  into Gridview Builder.