# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Album'

Tags: flutter, fetch-api, rest

```
[The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Album'.][1]


----------
[api code pasted here][2]

I am fetching data from internet using demo api and I want to show      
that data in a list view builder but i am getting error because of 
index in itembuilder please help me
```

gVKQ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQBY.png

Comment: No that's not right

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Album'.

Comment: please post code not images of code ...

Comment: Well, seems your `data` is not an array ...

Comment: your future should be Future<LIst<Album>>

Comment: after ading Future<LIst<Album>>this I am getting this error

Comment: A value of type 'Album' can't be returned from the function 'fetchAlbum' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<Album>>

Comment: Show us your fetchAlbum function or at least some of your code

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210)

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I am fetching same data just i want that in listview builder how to acheive that

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) for Listview

Answer (score 0):

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          **Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;**
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
```

one-time-read `DocumentReference.get`

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }
```

realtime changes `CollectionReference`  & `DocumentReference`

```
return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['full_name']),
              subtitle: Text(data['company']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

[doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

ExampleCollectionModel

```
class ExampleCollectionModel extends Equatable {
  final String uid;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final String displayName;
  final String avatarImageUrl;
  final String bio;

  const ExampleCollectionModel({
    required this.uid,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.displayName,
    required this.avatarImageUrl,
    required this.bio,
  });

  static const ExampleCollectionModel empty = ExampleCollectionModel(
    uid: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    displayName: '',
    avatarImageUrl: '',
    bio: '',
  );

  ExampleCollectionModel copyWith({
    String? uid,
    String? username,
    String? email,
    String? displayName,
    String? avatarImageUrl,
    String? bio,
  }) {
    return ExampleCollectionModel(
      uid: uid ?? this.uid,
      username: username ?? this.username,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      displayName: displayName ?? this.displayName,
      avatarImageUrl: avatarImageUrl ?? this.avatarImageUrl,
      bio: bio ?? this.bio,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'uid': uid,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'displayName': displayName,
      'avatarImageUrl': avatarImageUrl,
      'bio': bio,
    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toDocument() {
    return {
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'displayName': displayName,
      'avatarImageUrl': avatarImageUrl,
      'bio': bio,
    };
  }

  factory ExampleCollectionModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print('fromDocment ${data}');
    return ExampleCollectionModel(
      uid: doc.id,
      username: data['username'] ?? '',
      email: data['email'] ?? '',
      displayName: data['displayName'] ?? '',
      avatarImageUrl: data['avatarImageUrl'] ?? '',
      bio: data['bio'] ?? '',
    );
  }
```

** <strike>itemCount: snapshot.data!.title!.length !!!</strike> .**,

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Since you are fetching a list of albums you should return and adapt your code in consecuence.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Iterable albums = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return List<Album>.from(albums.map((album) => Album.fromJson(album)));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int? userId;
  final int? id;
  final String? title;

  Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(
    Map<String, dynamic> json,
  ) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<List<Album>> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Album>>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext c, int index) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data![index].title!);
                    });
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```