# Filter ListView with FutureBuilder?

Tags: json, list, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-listview

How can I upgrade this code into searching listview?
I try with using two lists and using **where** keyword but it not worked. some problem with filling data into a list, then printing the list it always shows `Instance of User`

```
class ListBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final FetchList fetchList;

  ListBuilder({required this.fetchList});

  @override
  _ListBuilderState createState() => _ListBuilderState();
}

class _ListBuilderState extends State<ListBuilder> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: widget.fetchList.getUsers(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return LoadingView();
        } else {
          if (snapshot.data.length > 0) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    // onChanged: onItemChanged,
                    // controller: _textController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Search Here by EmployeeId...',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return UserListTile(user: snapshot.data[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return EmptyView();
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here this list view build by using JSON data and using flutter FutureBuilder.

Comment: I think snapshot.data[index] is just indexing the whole  object or instance of the user. Try to add the name of what you are trying to access to like. snapshot.data[index]['nameOfEmployee']  or snapshot.data[index].nameOfEmployee.

Comment: If it says `Instance of...` then add a `toString()` method to that class. You have to find the objects that you are looking for. So either give some arguments to your API call (`widget.fetchList.getUsers()`) or first store this list, then throw everything out that you don't need.

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) I have used listview.builder using FutureBuilder hope it's helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing such things with a proper state management. While you can certainly achieve this within the widget, it will end with a poorly designed app. Have a look at this [brief tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial) on a todo list with filters using BLoC. Then there is a filtered list example which reads data from the network. I believe this makes more sense and is not so hard to learn