# Flutter List.Builder fetch JSON

Tags: json, list, flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-build

This is my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<User> _users = <User>[];
  List<User> _usersDisplay = <User>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchUsers().then((value){
      _users.addAll(value);
      _usersDisplay = _users;
      print(_usersDisplay.length);
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Users List'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (_usersDisplay.length > 0){
                return UserTile(user: this._usersDisplay[index]);
              }else{
                return LoadingView();
              }
            },
            itemCount: _usersDisplay.length + 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

While executing initStae() it prints _usersDisplay.length as **100** but only return LoadingView(). It not shows UserTile().

When checking `_usersDisplay.length` inside of build it is always 0. Why?

Also I **cannot define** List as this way:
`List<User> _users = List<User>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```dart
fetchUsers().then((value){
      _users.addAll(value);
      _usersDisplay = _users;
      print(_usersDisplay.length);
    });
```

to

```dart
fetchUsers().then((value){
      _users.addAll(value);
      _usersDisplay = _users;
      print(_usersDisplay.length);
      setState(() {})
});
```

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it's helpful to you in this answers I have used Futur and FutureBuilder for geting the data

Answer (score 2):

Use **[Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)** for JSON & List

```
FutureBuilder(
  builder: (context, snapshot) {

    // WHILE THE CALL IS BEING MADE AKA LOADING
    if (ConnectionState.active != null && !snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(child: Text('Loading'));
    }

    // WHEN THE CALL IS DONE BUT HAPPENS TO HAVE AN ERROR
    if (ConnectionState.done != null && snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error));
    }

    // IF IT WORKS IT GOES HERE!
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(snapshot.data[index].toString());
      },
    );
  },
  future: getAllTodos(),
),
```

Comment: How can I use Filtering or searching options when using Future Builder

Comment: Fetched data will be there in the Snapshot variable. You can access the snapshot as "snapshot.data" like list. Then, you can do whatever you want with that data.