# When i trying to get data from api im getting an error

Tags: flutter

Error is: **_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>'** is not a subtype of type 'List')

```
  Future<List<Data>> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('link'),
    headers: headers);
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonResponse.map((data) => new Data.fromJson(data)).toList();
  } else {
   throw Exception('Unexpected error occured!');
 }
}
```

my error field is: `List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);`

Comment: can you share your url?

Comment: i think problem is not url

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: remove List befor declaration and replace it with Map<String, dynamic> and see if it works.

Comment: i did but i have more error about jsonResponse fields: undefined name

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body); or  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

Comment: new error: TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Data' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')