# error in getting data from api in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, gridview

I want to get the names from the json plaeholder api in flutter. But it is giving error, the following is my code:

```
    FutureBuilder(
          future: getuser(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
if (snapshot.data==null) {
  return Container(
    child: Text("nothing"),
  );
}
else return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context,i){
    return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data[i].name),);  
    }
  );
          },
        )
```

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil  It is giving error in item count that "The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."

Comment: can you share your API url I will test it?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: check my answer hope its help to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil It worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Most welcome ,glad to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code I think your Problem has been solved and also add id and email also

> Your API Call Function

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getJobsData() async {
    String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

> Your Widget

```
     Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
            future: getJobsData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var name = snapshot.data[index]['name'];
                      var email = snapshot.data[index]['email'];
                      var id = snapshot.data[index]['id'];
                      return Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green.shade300),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              leading: Text(id.toString()),
                              title: Text(name),
                              subtitle: Text(email),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Your Result Screen like -> [image]