# Flutter display server data / response from json

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built a page which reads the json from `recipeURL` and I wish for it to display the `product_name` value in the json file. However for some reason my `future fetchData ()` class isn't being read as none of the text in my if else statement is being displayed. Am I missing a simple oversight here?

EDIT: The main dart file is my main screen. This is where my navbar is created. Users are redirected to other pages when they click on the corresponding icon. Im having trouble passing `BarcodePage(title:title);` as parameters in my main file,26th line, can be found under `Class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {`

**My main dart file:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'pages/BarcodePage.dart';
import 'pages/FoodPage.dart';
import 'pages/RecipePage.dart';
import 'pages/ShoppingPage.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: MyApp()),);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return MyAppState();
  }
}


class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 int _selectedPage =0;
 final _pageOptions= [
    FoodPage(),
    RecipePage(),
    BarcodePage(title: ,),
    ShoppingPage(),
  ];

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //title: 'Best B4',
        theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.teal,),
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         home: Scaffold (
           appBar: AppBar(
            title:Text(
              'BestB4',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'PacificoRegular',
                  fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
            elevation: 20,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code_2_rounded),
                tooltip: 'Add item',
                onPressed:(){
                   Navigator.push(
                     context, 
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BarcodePage()));
                },
              )
              ],
              //ONPRESSED MENU OPEN
           ),
            body:_pageOptions[_selectedPage],
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedItemColor: Colors.white70,
              iconSize: 40,
              selectedFontSize: 15,
              unselectedFontSize: 15,
              currentIndex:_selectedPage,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedPage  = index;
                });
              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon:Icon(Icons.restaurant_rounded),
                  label: 'Food',
                  ), //, title:Text('Food')
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon:Icon(Icons.menu_book_rounded),
                  label:'Recipes',
                  ),//, title:Text('Recipes')
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon:Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                  label:'Add',
                  ),//, title:Text('Add')
                 BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon:Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_rounded),
                  label:'Shopping',
                  ),//,title:Text('Shopping')
              ],
          ),
      ),
      ); 
  }
}
```

**My BarcodePage dart file:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as p;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:barcode_scan2/barcode_scan2.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';



class BarcodePage extends StatefulWidget{
  const BarcodePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _BarcodePageState createState() => _BarcodePageState();
}

var futuredata = {};

class _BarcodePageState extends State<BarcodePage> {
  int counter=0;
  String result= "";

  Future _scanBarcode() async{
    try{
      ScanResult scanResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      String barcodeResult = scanResult.rawContent;
      setState(() {
        result = barcodeResult;
      });

    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.cameraAccessDenied) {
        setState((){
        result = "CAMERA PERMISSION WAS DENIED. \n EDIT THIS IN YOUR SETTINGS";
      });
    }else {
      setState(() {
        result = "404 ERROR UNKNOWN $ex";
      });
    }
  } on FormatException {
    setState(() {
      result = "SCAN AN ITEM";
    });
  } catch (ex){
    setState(() {
        result = "404 ERROR UNKNOWN $ex";
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {}

  fetchmydata() async {
    var request = p.Request(
        'GET',
        Uri.parse(
            'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/5060391623139.json'));

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      var data = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      futuredata = json.decode(data);
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        title:Text('Add an item',
        style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Fredoka',
        fontSize: 25,
        ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                );
              else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(futuredata["product"]["product_name"].toString()),
                  subtitle: Text("France:" +
                      futuredata["product"]["product_name_en"].toString()),
                );
              else {
                return Container(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                );
              }
            },
            future: fetchmydata(),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        label: Text("Scan"),
        onPressed: _scanBarcode,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

**The Json file looks like this:**

*JSON LINK:* https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/5060391623139.json

[image]

Comment: you can refer my below answers for getting data from API and display it into Flutter.
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807671/13997210
  [3]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69131277/13997210
  [4]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210
  [5]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210
  [6]: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: could your add your json instead of image

Comment: @lava I have just added it to my original question, thank you!

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Thank you for your reads, I have tried to follow your answers in them but still having no luck.

Comment: Try use a FutureBuilder 

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can read your json like this

```
var futuredata = {};
var productname=    futuredata["product"]["product_name"]
```

Your fetch method like this

```
 fetchmydata() async {
    var request = p.Request(
        'GET',
        Uri.parse(
            'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/5060391623139.json'));

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      var data = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      futuredata = json.decode(data);
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

With model Class
SampleModel? Mymodel = null;
fetchmydata() async {
var request = p.Request(
'GET',
Uri.parse(
'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/5060391623139.json'));

```
    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      var data = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      futuredata = json.decode(data);
      Mymodel = SampleModel.fromJson(futuredata);
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

1. in the method we first read data from json as string or text
2. then we decode the string type or text from server to map type

[image]

[image]

[image]

**SampleCode**  [Dartpad live code check](https://dartpad.dev/?id=09827e6cda9d3b931fcf9e022774b88e)

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as p;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

var futuredata = {};

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {}

  fetchmydata() async {
    var request = p.Request(
        'GET',
        Uri.parse(
            'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/5060391623139.json'));

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      var data = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      futuredata = json.decode(data);
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                );
              else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(futuredata["product"]["product_name"].toString()),
                  subtitle: Text("France:" +
                      futuredata["product"]["product_name_en"].toString()),
                );
              else {
                return Container(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                );
              }
            },
            future: fetchmydata(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Sample ModelClass**

```
///
/// Code generated by jsonToDartModel https://ashamp.github.io/jsonToDartModel/
///
class SampleModelProduct {
/*
{
  "_id": "5060391623139",
  "_keywords": [
    "peanut"
  ],
  "product_name": "Peanut butter",
  "product_name_en": "Peanut butter",
  "product_name_fr": "Peanut butter"
}
*/

  String? Id;
  List<String?>? Keywords;
  String? productName;
  String? productNameEn;
  String? productNameFr;

  SampleModelProduct({
    this.Id,
    this.Keywords,
    this.productName,
    this.productNameEn,
    this.productNameFr,
  });

  SampleModelProduct.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    Id = json['_id']?.toString();
    if (json['_keywords'] != null) {
      final v = json['_keywords'];
      final arr0 = <String>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v.toString());
      });
      Keywords = arr0;
    }
    productName = json['product_name']?.toString();
    productNameEn = json['product_name_en']?.toString();
    productNameFr = json['product_name_fr']?.toString();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['_id'] = Id;
    if (Keywords != null) {
      final v = Keywords;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v);
      });
      data['_keywords'] = arr0;
    }
    data['product_name'] = productName;
    data['product_name_en'] = productNameEn;
    data['product_name_fr'] = productNameFr;
    return data;
  }
}

class SampleModel {
/*
{
  "code": "5060391623139",
  "product": {
    "_id": "5060391623139",
    "_keywords": [
      "peanut"
    ],
    "product_name": "Peanut butter",
    "product_name_en": "Peanut butter",
    "product_name_fr": "Peanut butter"
  },
  "status": 1,
  "status_verbose": "product found"
}
*/

  String? code;
  SampleModelProduct? product;
  int? status;
  String? statusVerbose;

  SampleModel({
    this.code,
    this.product,
    this.status,
    this.statusVerbose,
  });

  SampleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    code = json['code']?.toString();
    product = (json['product'] != null)
        ? SampleModelProduct.fromJson(json['product'])
        : null;
    status = json['status']?.toInt();
    statusVerbose = json['status_verbose']?.toString();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['code'] = code;
    if (product != null) {
      data['product'] = product!.toJson();
    }
    data['status'] = status;
    data['status_verbose'] = statusVerbose;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: no i didnt. i direct convert the json string to map and call it

Comment: i just adde sample factory class .i used online model class genertator

Comment: based on the question . i only added product name .this json contain more than 100 properties so skip that.

Comment: The flutter generator create the .g.dart file reducing the keystroking.  It uses the class properties to create the map

Comment: thanks .i know some of this properties custom object type .so writing  100 properties and there object type creating  and use this devdependecy is time take.so using this online converter is better.

Comment: Thank you so much @lava & @Golden Lion for your help, this was an issue I was stuck on for days! Only issue Im now having is passing the title variable as the parameter for `BarcodePage()` on my main screen. Idea is when the barcode button is pressed in main navbar it directs the user to the BarcodePage.  Button works fine. Im just having trouble trying to pass title as `BarcodePage(title:title)` however its now saying title is an undefined name.  Code is here: [link] (https://www.codepile.net/pile/9Qn1kEz2)

Comment: you didnt add barcodepage page .please add

Comment: `class MyAppState extends StatefulWidget {
  var title;

  MyAppState({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyAppState> createState() => _MyAppStateState();
}`

Comment: you can pass named parameters to a constructor by changing the constructor to myclass({this.field1}) final string field1;

Comment: call in my app `BarcodePage(title:'mybarcode'))` insteada`Barcode()` you used required  attribute for `title` argument.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a .g.dart file using flutter packages pub run build_runner build.   flutter automatically will create your binding class factory.  once you have the binding classes created flutter will automatically code your binding class, including nested classes.  I personally think automation is the way to handle all interactions with json from the server.  The reason you want to use the future .g.dart code generator is to reduce the possibility of error and incorrect type casting.

```
file.dart
factory ProductView.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductFromJson(json);
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ProductViewToJson(this);

file.g.dart


ProductView _$ProductViewFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return
ProductView(
    json['field1'] as int,
    json['field2'] as String,
    json['field3'] == null
        ? null
        : DateTime.parse(json['field3'] as String),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ProjectViewToJson(ProductView instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'field1': instance.field1,
      'field2': instance.field2,
      'field3': instance.field3?.toIso8601String(),
    };
```

decoding the json

```
 var client = http.Client();
      Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
      headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers).timeout(_TIMEOUT);
    var parsed = json.decode(response.body);
    var view = ProductView.fromJson(parsed);
```