# I want to access response coming from API in array format in flutter how many ways are there to access it and use it in UI?

Tags: android, flutter, rest, dart, observable

I am unable to get the data from below API response.Is there something called Observable pattern which I can use here? Please guide

API response is in this format:

```
[{"userId":160,"userName":"Reshma","userMobile":"8080808080","userEmail":"reshma@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$BgzWbEGGjw4mloo92merguOSrFe91ir/J9bUDO2qv.ZgTmdeum4.y","userPassword":"1221","role":"ADMIN","userCity":"Pune"}]
```

Please refer below code:

**LoginController.dart**

```
static Future<List<UserLogin>> login(String email, String password) async {
    print(email);
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'http://192.168.0.111:8081/AtdochubJ-3/user/login?useremail=$email&userpassword=$password'));
   ;
    print(email);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('response++++ $response');
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      return parsed.map<UserLogin>((json) => UserLogin.fromJson(json)).toList();
     
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Document');
    }
  }
```

**LoginPage.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:AtDocHUB/Model/User.dart';
import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/AppointmentPageFE.dart';
import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/homePageAdmin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:AtDocHUB/Controller/LoginController.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'User Login';

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        // appBar: AppBar(
        //   title: const Text(appTitle),
        // ),
        body: MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  late Future<UserLogin> futureLogin;

  late Future _futureAuth;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextStyle style = const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontSize: 20.0,
  );

  List<UserLogin> logs = [];
  List<UserLogin> userRole = [];
  String email = '';

  String pass = '';

 

  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pwController = TextEditingController();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 130,
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: SizedBox(
                              height: 155,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/AtDocHublogo.png",
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 45,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          style: style,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                              hintText: "Email",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: pwController,
                          style: style,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                              hintText: "Password",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 35.0),
                        MaterialButton(
                            height: 55,
                            child: Text("Login",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: style.copyWith(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168),
                           
                            onPressed: () {
                              final String email = emailController.text;

                              final String pass = pwController.text;
                              LoginController.login(email, pass);
                              List<UserLogin> res =
                                  LoginController.login(email, pass)
                                      as List<UserLogin>;
                              print(res[0].role);
                             
                              print(res[0].role);

                              if (res != []) {
                                if (res[0].role == 'ADMIN') {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (_) => homePageAdmin()));
                                } else {
                                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                      msg: "User Doesn't Exists",
                                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                                      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
                                      textColor: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 12.0);
                                }
                              }
}   )
                      ])))),
    );
  }}
```

Comment: if you want to get data from API refer my answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69131277/13997210)

Answer (score 1):

In your `LoginController.dart`, do this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

then

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('response++++ $response');
      final parsed = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
      return parsed.map((e) => UserLogin.fromJson(e)).toList();
      
     
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Document');
    }
```

your api response is a List of map but you were casting it to map.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out

Comment: @Minal Suryawanshi does it help you?

Comment: Hello @eamirho3ein not implemented yet but will surely let you know once i do. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that, if it was helpful please approve and upvote it so other people find it easier. @MinalSuryawanshi

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `LoginController.login` works, wait for a response like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  final String email = emailController.text;
  final String pass = pwController.text;

  List<UserLogin> res = await LoginController.login(email, pass);
  print(res[0].role);
}
```

Read more about [Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await).