# I just need to get the text title and text description from the api

Tags: json, flutter, text, containers

Here is my JSON

```json
[ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Всем моим братьям салам",
        "description": "Салам всем моим братьям",
        "created_at": "2021-09-14T23:55:23.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-14T23:55:23.000000Z"
    },
]
```

My code

```
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 52.w, right: 25.w, left: 25.w),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
                  width: 355.w,
                  child: Text('',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 29.sp),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.w, right: 25.w, left: 25.w),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
                  width: 319.w,
                  child: Text(
                   '',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.sp),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

First, you make a list from your data then pass the list over `ListView.builder`

 HTTP request function

```
Future<List<Item>> _getItemdata (String url) async {

Uri url = Uri.parse(url);
final response = await http.get(url);
var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

print('data: $data');
return data.map((itemJson) => Item.fromJson(itemJson)).toList();
}
```

Model class

```
class Item {
  int id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Item({this.id, this.title, this.description, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt});

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Get the list

```
List<Item> itemList = await getItemData("your url");
```

UI:

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ScrollPhysics(),
itemCount: itemList.length;
itemBuilder:(context, index){
return Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 52.w, right: 25.w, left: 25.w),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
                  width: 355.w,
                  child: Text("${itemList[index].title}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 29.sp),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.w, right: 25.w, left: 25.w),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
                  width: 319.w,
                  child: Text(
                   Text("${itemList[index].description}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.sp),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
}
)
```

Comment: Where to add my URL address?

Comment: add url under getData, if it will api call you call getdata over future builder instead of listview builder

Comment: You can write an example adding a URL

Answer (score 0):

For the given piece of code, Let me assume your json data is assigned to a variable "data".

```
var newData = json.decode(data);
String title = newData[0]["title"];
String subTitle = newData[0]["description"];
```