# Correct way of using FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

So I have some question abaout how to correctly use FutureBuilder. I read somewhere that we should store the future in a variable and call that variable in the FutureBuilder instead of the future service. But how do we initalize the initial value of that variable? When I tired this, it always gives `LateInitializationError: Field '_dataFuture@28307501' has not been initialized.` and should wait until the data is loaded.

```
  late Future<List<TransaksiResp>> _dataFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    transaksiService = TransaksiService();
    getUserPrefs().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _dataFuture = transaksiService.getTransaksi(user[2]);});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<TransaksiResp>>(
                future: _dataFuture,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(snapshot);
                    return Center(
                      child: Text("Error"),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData){
                    List<TransaksiResp> response = snapshot.data;
                    return _buildListView(response);
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: Container(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is getUserPrefs method to get user data from Shared Preference

```
 Future<void> getUserPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    user = prefs.getStringList("user")!;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: you should use `_dataFuture = someMethodReturningYourFuture();` inside `initState`

Comment: already put it in initState, right after calling `getUserPrefs`, or should I call it directly inside `initState?` Because I need the data from `getUserPrefs` to call for the service

Comment: no, you are assigning `_dataFuture = ...` inside `.then` callback that is called after `build` method is called - to check it add one `print('build')` inside `build()` method and another `print('then')` inside `.then` callback

Comment: basically you should use `_dataFuture = someMethodReturningYourFuture();` without any `setState` etc, just write an `async` method that returns a `Future`, for more read [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

Get the answer, because I need the data from SharedPreferences, I need to wait for the function to finish first

```
  _getService() async {
    await getUserPrefs();
    return await transaksiService.getTransaksi(user[2]);
  }
```

Then calling it in `iniState` and save it in a variable

```
 _dataFuture = _getService();
```

Comment: btw you can just call `return  transaksiService.getTransaksi(user[2]);` - no need for `await` here, also i would return user data from `getUserPrefs` so you can avoid global `user` variable / field: `final user = await getUserPrefs();`

Answer (score 0):

- **FutureBuilder** removes boilerplate code.
- FutureBuilder Widget is used to create widgets based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future.  It is necessary for Future to
  be obtained earlier either through a change of state or change in dependencies.

If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it's helpful to you in this examples I have used FutureBuilder refer it.

refer documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for **FutureBuilder**

You aslo refer [here](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9)

Hope its help to you

Comment: I use this method before, and some said we should save it to a variable, not directly calling the service

Comment: What was your exact problem I mean you get data to `JSON API`

Comment: tbh, there is no problem for it. I just want to know ho to use FutureBuilder correctly

Comment: refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYN46233cws) video