# How to get list from JSON data to display in widget?

Tags: android, json, flutter

I have been making a simple app which displays crypto coins and their price, data, market cap etc. I am using CoinGeckGo API.

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Coin {
  String? coinName;
  String? coinPrice;
  String? coinImgUrl;
  String? coinVol;
  Coin(
      {@required this.coinName,
      @required this.coinPrice,
      @required coinImgUrl,
      @required coinVol});
}

class Coins {
  Future<List<Coin>> fetchCoinsData() async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(
        "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false");
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    final json = await jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<Coin> coins = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      Coin coin = Coin(
        coinImgUrl: json[i]["image"].toString(),
        coinName: json[i]["symbol"].toString(),
        coinPrice: json[i]["current_price"].toString(),
        coinVol: json[i]["total_volume"].toString(),
      );
     coins.add(coin);
    }

    return coins;
  }
}
```

this is my function to fetch data from json api and add them into list so that i get values from that list to display in widget.

but when I am calling this function in init state, and assign fetched return value to a list i get output "Instance of 'Coin', but it should be like `{coinName:'btc',coinPrice: '48000', coinVol: 478965455`
like that
below is code i am calling function inside initstate.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Coin> my_list = [];
  bool? _isLoading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    Coins().fetchCoinsData().then((List<Coin> value) {
      print(value);
      my_list = value;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

[image: This is what output I am getting instead of coin data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Your API Call function:

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> getCoinsData() async {
    String url =
        'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: getCoinsData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var name = snapshot.data![index]['name'];
                    var symbol = snapshot.data![index]['symbol'];
                    var image = snapshot.data![index]['image'];
                    var currentPrice =
                        snapshot.data![index]['current_price'];
                    var totalVolume =
                        snapshot.data![index]['total_volume'];
                    var id = snapshot.data![index]['id'];
                    return Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green.shade300),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                              child: Image.network(image),
                            ),
                            title: Text(name),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              "Symbol - " +
                                  symbol +
                                  "\nTotal Volume -" +
                                  totalVolume.toString() +
                                  "\nCurrent Price -" +
                                  currentPrice.toString(),
                            ),
                            trailing: Text(id),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Your Result Screen: [image]