# how can i display my json in a web without using widget as json

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future main() async {
  var target = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(myLink),
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
  );
  String body = (utf8.decode(target.bodyBytes));
  myDecodedData = json.decode(body);
  runApp(myDecodedData);
}
```

now I want to display my code as json in a web pag

Comment: If you get data from API refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709502/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68594656/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: yes a got it from API but i dont want to use widget ,, only display my data as json on web@RavindraS.Patil

Comment: If you display anything on web screen or mobile screen it not possible without using Widget you must used any widget

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display something, you *need* a widget. You cannot display something without any widget.

However, if you want the simplest way of just showing your JSON, you could encode it back to text and use the `Text` widget to show it all, the whole JSON in one widget.

That is technically still "a widget", but it's the least number of widgets you will have.

Comment: i did that before but i want my data as json not as text

Comment: If you encode something as json, *it is text*. The sentence "I want it as json, not as text" is meaningless. Please explain in detail what it is you want.

Comment: i want to call this web in postman so postman cant read this web cuz its a text thats why i want to display it as json

Comment: You cannot "display it as json". It's a webpage. You already *have* an API that delivers JSON, perfect for postman, why not use it directly?

Comment: ill create a web server to get api throw this web server

Comment: its all about security

Comment: Well, Flutter is made for frontend UI applications. If you want to write a web *server* I'm sure it's possible in Dart, but Flutter might not be the best framework for it.  You can try to start [here](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver), but I would consider using a different language and framework that is actually made it it's purpose to build web APIs instead of (mis)using Flutter for it.