# Expected a value of type 'Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic>' but got one of type 'List<dynamic>' while making api post request

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-web

i'm building a flutter web page with data retrived from an api, almost everything works fine but i have this problem. The api accept just one parameter that is '{"url":""}', and everything in my code works because if i try to print the result in the console it works. The only problem i have is with displaying data on screen, flutter gave me this error even though i'm passing him the type he expected.

here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final headers = {"Content-type": "text/plain"};
  final json = '{"url": ""}';
  final response = await post(
      Uri.parse('myapikey'),
      headers: headers,
      body: json);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    print(response.body);
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String url;

  Album({
    required this.url,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(url: json['']);
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.url);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

can someone help me?

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried this one before, but got the same error because i have just one parameter that my api accept, not 3 like the json placeholder

Comment: Can you add your API url

Comment: nope, unfortunately i cannot, it's not my property so for safety reason i cannot post the url

Answer (score 0):

The factory in the Album class expects a **Map with the keys of type List** and **values of type dynamic**, but your json body is `{"url": ""}` which, after decoding it with`jsonDecode(response.body)`, has a type of `Map<String, String>` and this **IS NOT THE SAME** as `Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic>`.

```dart
class Album {
  final String url;

  Album({
    required this.url,
  });
  
  // This factory causes the error
  factory Album.fromJson(Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(url: json['']);
  }
}
```

Also when you want to retrieve the value of url you have to write `json["url"]` and not `json['']`, because `"url"` is the key for `""` in `'{"url": ""}'`.

**SOLUTION**: So you should change the factory to accept an argument of type `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`, and change the key for retrieving `""` from `json['']` to `json["url"]`.

```
  factory Album.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(url: json["url"]);
  }
```

Also see this working DartPad example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final headers = {"Content-type": "text/plain"};
  final json = '{"url": ""}';
  final response = Response(
    json,
    200,
    request: Request(
      "post",
      Uri.parse('myapikey'),
    ),
    headers: headers,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    print(response.body);
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final String url;

  Album({
    required this.url,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(url: json["url"]);
  }
}

void main() {
  fetchAlbum();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried your solution, and the problem went from "Expected a value of type 'Map<List<dynamic>, dynamic>' but got one of type 'List<dynamic>' while making api post request" to "Expected a value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'."
So it's the same error more or less. I also tried the solution your suggested me (the one worked through DartPad) but with this code the console response.body became just {"url":""} and not the data inside the api, so that's what it's printed in the console

Comment: In the dartpad example i constructed a `Response` object myself (`final response = Response(...)`) instead of using the post method, so obviously the body will not change. Try using the post method with your API key like in the code example in your question (`final response = await post(...)`).