# How to integrate Node JS API with Flutter APP?

Tags: node.js, flutter

I have created simple API to store Username and Password in Node JS. Now i want to connect with Flutter.
And I am using http package in flutter.[HTTP version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ8Pa.png)
So anyone can help me with this ?

I have tried this..

```
void _saveForm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
    }

    var data = {
      "email": formData['email'].toString(),
      "password": formData['password'].toString(),
    };
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(data);

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You should try to host your Node API on server or just use it locally refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533647/13997210) answer for getting API response in flutter app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by following few simple steps.

1. Creating the API in nodejs (which you already have)
2. Connect your computer to a wifi network and type command `ipconfig` on the terminal. Copy the ipv4 address and then you can make a request to your node server from the mobile app (flutter) in the following way:
3. If your using the physical emulator (your mobile phone) make sure it is connected to the same network as your pc is.

Post Request:

```
http.Response response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse('http://192.168.68.58:4000/YOUR-API'),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(
              <String, String>{'username': "Amarendra", 'password': "baahubali"}),
        );
```

Access the reponse body:

```
  variableName = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Get Request:

```
  http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('IPAddress/YOUR-API'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );
    print(response.body);
```

You can wrap the above code in a function, and place the function in the stateful widget.

Later you can call this function from the `void initState()`

I always make this implementation in my apps. Hope it works for you as well.